# Syncing folders/directories in Finder

Tags: data-synchronization, backup

I manually backup my home directory onto an external USB drive.

So far, I have to override everything data on each backup which, of course, results in long back up times.

Is there a free and simple tool that I can use to sync folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 10.7 Finder now suggest merging folders when you copy and paste over an existing folder:

[image]

Comment: This is great! I should have seen this before. But because I this is always done in a hassle, I did not notice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) or [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) are two apps that make doing sync-style updates easy.[Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427) automatically does sync-style updates, but also does versioning.